# View on top of another View

Tags: java, android

I have a Linear layout in which there is an Image View. I would like to add a Text View on top of it. Please share the XML Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service, you've literally just demanded code. Show your effort so far and explain what specific problem(s) you are encountering. Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To add a TextView on top of an ImageView just use a RelativeLayout as the parent instead of LinearLayout. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"            
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bubble"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/abc_action_mode_done"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will result in an overlay:

[image]